# How to reduce slot number for a running job in Hadoop MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, slot

Any one knows how to reduce the slot number for a running job in a right way which can avoid the re-execution?

For example, a  job has 4 map slots and I want to decrease it to 2 map slots when it is running.

I have tried to reconfigure `mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum` at runtime and restart the tasktracker quickly, but an error "task tracker lost" occurs and the map tasks completed by the restarted tasktracker are re-executed. I think the reason why they are re-executed is that the jobtracker believes the restarted tasktracker is lost. So, I extend the expiry interval of the tasktracker, but it doesn't work.

Comment: By extending the expiry interval of tasktracker, did you mean modifying `mapred.task.timeout`?

Comment: What is your use case ?

Comment: It is mapred.tasktracker.expiry.interval   . I also have tried task.timeout, it didn't work

Comment: when the job runs ahead of schedule, I want to reduce slot number to save computation cost, but I don't want to reduce it like a node failure which causes the task re-execution.